# It is possible to migrate existing apk release to App Bundle format?

Tags: android

We have existing android app with apk release on play store. Can we use app bundle for release instead of Apk existing app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes It's simple to update app using App Bundle. first,

Create new release of your app by increase 1 `versionCode` and then [Enroll into app signing by Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423). After that publish newly created app bundle to play console rest of all things google handle it.

For more information visit [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Your new update can be an App Bundle.
Please go through the following guide by Google to know more about how to do this.
[App Bundle Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle)

We recently moved from traditional APK uploading to App Bundle, it's very easy, just go through the guide once.

Answer (score 1):

if you are going to update your app in playstore ,you must increase +1 of the   application version. That case old apk is not valid. Instead of Apk you can create/release new bundle for new version of app.